# hide the inputToolbar in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) for my chat application. When there is no internet activity I would like to hide the inputToolbar

I tried this, but that does not work:

```
    self.inputToolbar.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0,height: 0)
```

When I set this, then for less than a second it's gone:

```
    self.inputToolbar.preferredDefaultHeight = 0
```

Any idea how to do this? 
Maybe disabling the inputToolbar could also be good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing from superview and having to add back as a subview, why not just use:

> [self.inputToolbar setHidden:YES];

Comment: Of course that's a lot cleaner! I am now using your solution, thanks.

Comment: This solution has a minus - the VC still thinks there is a bar and shows content and scroll indicatior with a bottom indent.

Answer (score 4):

I found a better solution which doesn't have any side effects.
You can make the actions in a **descendant** class of JSQMessagesViewController.

**1.** Make this method of base class available for you:

```
@interface JSQMessagesViewController ()
- (void)jsq_setCollectionViewInsetsTopValue:(CGFloat)top 
                                bottomValue:(CGFloat)bottom;
@end
```

**2.** Override parent realization of method (called when size changed):

```
- (void)jsq_updateCollectionViewInsets {
    CGFloat topInset = self.topLayoutGuide.length + self.topContentAdditionalInset;
    CGFloat bottomInset = 0.0;
    [self jsq_setCollectionViewInsetsTopValue:topInset bottomValue:bottomInset];
}
```

**3.** Write the method to hide input toolbar forever:

```
- (void)hideInputToolbar {
    self.inputToolbar.hidden = YES;
    [self jsq_updateCollectionViewInsets];
}
```

**4.** Enjoy!

Comment: Hi. You mean create a bridging-header? Or just create  `customclass.m/h` files?

Comment: Just create a usual custom class whose parent class is JSQMessagesViewController.
Like this: @interface MyMessageViewController : JSQMessagesViewController
Then put above code to MyMessageViewController.m file.

Comment: Yes but my project is in Swift so do I need a bridging header file? Since JSQ is already Objective-C I can just create a subclass with new .h and .m and not worry about a header file?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this will work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.inputToolbar.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: You should use the approved awnser

Comment: When I use this code there is the exception with a reason: 'An instance <memory_address> of class JSQMessagesComposerTextView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.